# Transactions for manager level SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

The manager should be able to:

- Add, Edit and Delete information for an employee
- Obtain a sales report for a particular month
- Produce a comprehensive listing of all items being advertised on the site

My question is if I want to add edit or delete infor for an employee
for example if i want to edit

```
  UPDATE employee
  SET    salary =  20,000
  where  name = "Adam Gibson"
```

How can I know this is the transaction for manager? Is there a command says a transaction is specifically for someone?

And this is a homework question. I am required to write those transaction for manager, but it didn't say what information i should add edit or delete for an employee.

I have an output table for employee with some information on it

how can I say that manager have the power to add edit or delete information ?

Tables for manager and employee

```
    CREATE TABLE Employee(
       SSN INTEGER,
       Start_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
       Hourly_Rate INTEGER,
       Manager INTEGER,

       PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
       FOREIGN KEY (Manager) REFERENCES Manager(SSN), 
       FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Person(SSN)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Manager(
       SSN INTEGER,
       Start_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
       Hourly_Rate INTEGER,

       PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
       FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Person(SSN)
    );
```

output table

Employee Data

```
EmpID   SSN Fname   Lname   Address City    State   ZipCode Telephone   StartDateHourly  Rate    Role
```

There are 50 employees in the output, I will just put the name of the columns in there

Comment: What source tables do you have? If you have an Employee table, does it contain a flag for Manager?

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this for, e.g. which **concrete database** do you use? Oracle? MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? SQL Server? Please **update** your tags accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

If

```
not (Manager is null)
```

then the employee is also a manager and has the necessary rights to issue the update mentioned in your question.